# Distinguish iphone 4 vs 5 vs 6 vs 6+ portrait with size class

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard, size-classes

I have design with different offsets and sizes of elements for each kind of device.
Is there any way to set different values to constraints in storyboard (using size classes or whatever) for different iphones in portrait (they all are compact|regular) ?

If no — what's the best way to solve such task?

## UPDATE

For example I have logo, on **each** (including different iphones) platform top offset for logo is different (even in points).

I want to avoid code like that

```
- (CGFloat)topLogoConstraintAccordingToSize:(CGSize)size {
    CGFloat top = 0;
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
        if (size.height > size.width){
            top = 56;
        } else {
            top = 35;
        }
    } else {
        if (IS_IPHONE_4){
            top = 36;
        } else if (IS_IPHONE_5){
            top = 22;
        } else if (IS_IPHONE_6){
            top = 50;
        } else if (IS_IPHONE_6_PLUS){
            top = 56;
        }
    }
    return top;
}
```

//somewhere else in universe

```
self.logoTopConstraint.constant = [self topLogoConstraintAccordingToSize:size];
```

Also I don't want to create separate storyboard for each platform — it's even worse.

Comment: Other then these two proposed solutions, maybe you could create logo with offsets ( several different pictures ) and assign logo through code with the device name in it (which is ugly as hell, if you ask me). The fourth solution could be: impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect constraint with code behind and change the value as you wish.

This could look like:
- in .h file:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *constraint;
```

-in .m file:

```
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"])    constraint.constant=1;//put value you want instead of 1,2 and 3
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])    constraint.constant=1;
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"])    constraint.constant=2;
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,2"])    constraint.constant=2;
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,3"])    constraint.constant=2;
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,4"])    constraint.constant=2;
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,1"])    constraint.constant=2;
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,2"])    constraint.constant=2;
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,1"])    constraint.constant=3;
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,2"])    constraint.constant=3;
```

But, I am not really sure what are you trying to achieve. Every element is in points, and should look fine(1x,2x and 3x). Can you explain a bit more what do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you did it programmatically you could test against the screen height (or width) eg:

```
//iphone 5
if UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height == 568.0 {
// your code here
}
```

iphone screen heights are as follows:

iphone 5 = 568.0

iPhone 6/6s/7 = 667.0

iphone 6/7 plus = 736.0

Answer (score -1):

Paste this lines in AppDelegate.m below headers

```
 #define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v) ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:(v) options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
 #define IS_WIDESCREEN ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```

and in application did Launch

```
       UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = nil;
      if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6.0"))
   {


    if (IS_WIDESCREEN)
    {

        //4 inch screen
        mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];


    }
    else
    {

        if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {
            mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad" bundle:nil];

        }
        else
        {
            //3.5 inch screen
            mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_legacy_IPhone" bundle:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with constraints hence the answer is irrelevant to the question